# Get wordpress post video url

Tags: wordpress, post, video

I have insert a YouTube video link in my WordPress post. It properly showing the video on the front end. Now i want to get the embed code of video on my another WordPress page.

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

To quickly embed a YouTube video, simply copy the video’s URL from your web browser’s address bar while viewing the video:

[image: youtube url]

And paste it on a line by itself in your post/page editor:

[image: editor]

WordPress will take care of the rest!

**Embedding with a Shortcode:**

To customize the video’s size and settings, use a shortcode.

For example, this shortcode:

```
[youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaNH56Vpg-A&w=640&h=385]
```

produces the video, which is wider than the default embed

Comment: i want the same url of video dynamically on my other page where i using the excerpt of post